# Express js conditional statement to choose between middleware modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have an endpoint in `express.js` which is conditionally choosing between middlware callbacks to execute:

```
const middleware1 = require('./m1')
const middleware2 = require('./m2')
app.get('/call', async (req, res) => {
  if (req.code === 'something') {
    middleware1.call
  } else if (req.code === 'something else') {
    middleware2.call
  } else {
    res.send({
      done: "done"
    })
  }
})
```

#### middleware1

```
module.exports = {
  call : async function(req, res, next) {
    // does some async stuff with req
    // sends it as response
    res.send({data: "data"})
  }
}
```

Similar idea for `middleware2`. The problem is once `middleware1` or middleware2` is called the request is not closing. However if, as a test, I remove the conditional statement and call one middleware immediately like so:

```
app.get('/call', middleware1.call);
```

This works immediately, why is that? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What do you mean with `the request is not closing`? does it never returns a response? Take a shot adding `next()` at the end of your middlewares and adding `return` at middleware call you're doing on the `/call` endpoint, so it would look like `return middleware1.call(req, res, next)`. afaik you can use this req code conditional logic in just one middleware and call it BEFORE the definition of the endpoint tag, just like this: `app.get(yourMiddleware, '/call', async (req, res, next) ...`

Comment: you have to actually call the middleware: `middleware1.call(req,res)`

Comment: Usually there are 3 arguments pased in any middeware `req, res, next`. Do you do this while calling `middleware1.call`?

Comment: `res.send` should send the response back, however, in your case it seems the call to any middleware is not happening. Internally, res.send does call the next.

Comment: @giggo1604 adding `(req, res)` to middleware call worked.

Comment: You need to invoke the function by using the invocation operator (`()`). The `app.get('/call', middleware1.call)` works as you are passing a function reference and express invokes the function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu might need to do this:

```
const middleware2 = require('./m2')
app.get('/call', async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.code === 'something') { 
    middleware1.execute(req, res, next); // you were not calling the method
  } else if (req.code === 'something else') {
    middleware2.execute(req, res, next);
  } else {
    res.send({
      done: "done"
    })
  }
})
```

```
module.exports = {
// call is the reserved keyword use something different
  execute : async function(req, res, next) {
    // does some async stuff with req
    // sends it as response
    res.send({data: "data"})
  }
}
```

`res.send` should send the response back, however, in your case it seems the call to any middleware is not happening. Internally, `res.send` does call the next to send the response back and should send it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `next()` to the end of your middleware. So that the request gets passed to the next function in the stack. More on middleware here [Writing middleware for use in Express apps](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html).